# when i press back space, commas are inserted in input box, and the numbers dont get formatted as required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am making an input box, which inserts commas as thousand separator (Indian currency style) , while typing . it is working fine. but when I press backspace it inserts unnecessary commas and the commas dont get rearranged.

for example: when i input 1111111 i get the result 11,11,111 , but when i press backspace and make it  11,11,11 it dont get adjusted.,.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input.number').keyup(function(event) {
        // skip for arrow keys
        if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
        // format number
        $(this).val(function(index, value) {
            var x=value;
            x=x.toString();
            var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
            var otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
            if(otherNumbers != '')
                lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
            var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
            return res;
            //document.getElementById("textInput").value=res;   
            //return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        });
    });
</script>
<input class="number" style="width:140px; height:40px; outline: 0;" >
```

Comment: You might want to format your code a little, don't you think?

Comment: i get it, sorry i need to rephrase the question, when i press backspace for example: when i input 1111111 i get the result 11,11,111 , but when i press backspace and make it  11,11,11 it dont get adjusted., @dfsq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a simple `console.log(x)` in your callback function (after the `var x=value;` line) shows what the problem is:

When you already have `1,111` in the input field, and then press the backspace key with the cursor at the end of it, your input value for the function is `1,11` (because backspace removed the last character of the current value) – and then you are taking the last three characters from this with your `var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);` line, which gets you `,11`, which you then append again to your final result – and therefor you get two consecutive commas.

I think the easiest way around this would be to just remove all commas before you start working on the value,

```
$(this).val(function(index, value) {
     var x=value.replace(/,/g, "");
     // rest of code here
```

– that gives you a “clean” value to work on, without any commas in it, so that your logic of locating parts of that value via substring method does not get thrown of by them.

(And the value of an input field is always a string, so `x=x.toString();` is superfluous.)

Comment: i tried , but it isnt working, i am not getting the desired result

Comment: i am also adding my  solution , plz correct if i went wrong or redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
                                $('input.number').keyup(
                                function(event) 
                                    {
                                        // skip for arrow keys
                                        if((event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57)||(event.which >= 96 && event.which <= 105)) 
                                        {
                                        // format number
                                        $(this).val(
                                        function(index, value)   
                                            {
                                            var x=value;
                                            var x=value.replace(/,/g, "");
                                            x=x.toString();
                                            var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
                                            var otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
                                            if(otherNumbers != '')
                                                    lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
                                            var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
                                            return res;
                                            //document.getElementById("textInput").value=res;                                               
                                            //return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                                            }
                                            );
                                        }
                                        else
                                            {                                               

                                            if(event.which == 8)
                                                {   
                                                $(this).val(function(index, value)   
                                                    {
                                                        var x=parseFloat(value.replace(/,/g, ''));
                                                        x=x.toString();
                                                        var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
                                                        var otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
                                                        if(otherNumbers != '')
                                                                    lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
                                                        var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
                                                        return res;
                                                        //document.getElementById("textInput").value=res;                                               
                                                        //return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                                                    }
                                                    );                                                          
                                                }
                                            else
                                                {
                                                    return;
                                                }



                                            }
                                    }

                                );
                                </script>
```

Comment: No only quite redundant, but some parts don’t make any sense – like f.e. using `parseFloat`, only to then make it a string value again in the next line, what is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: And I don’t see why you would need an extra branch to handle the backspace key – if you are already using my suggested solution to simply remove the commas from the value before working on it, then what is that supposed to accomplish? It might “work”, but it seems like you are complicating things without any necessity.

Comment: yup, i get it, i have used your solution, in my sloution backspace , causes error in commas arrangement